# How the detect whether a file with a typical extension exists by using Fortran

Tags: fortran

My problem is like this,
Say there is a folder named as 'Input' containing some files. The names of these files are like *.nod, *.elem etc. The major part of the file name is given by the end-users.
Now, I want to detect whether any *.nod exists in the folder and get the major part of the file name to generate some output files.

For example, if there is test.nod. Firstly, I want to detect whether this file exists. If yes, I need to get the character 'test', and use it to name a output file, e.g., 'test.rst'

I did not find any solution of this problem on Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Found at Rosettacode.org:

```
LOGICAL :: file_exists
INQUIRE(FILE="input.txt", EXIST=file_exists)   ! file_exists will be TRUE if the file
                                               ! exists and FALSE otherwise
INQUIRE(FILE="/input.txt", EXIST=file_exists)
```

Edit:

```
CHARACTER(10) :: extension="nod"
CHARACTER(255) :: cfile

IF(os == "unix") THEN
CALL system('ls -1 *.'//TRIM(extension)//'> list')
ELSE
CALL system('dir /b/on *.'//TRIM(extension)//'> list')
ENDIF
```

open and read file `list` with the format "(A)" e.g.

```
OPEN(15,file="list")    
READ(15,"(A)",END=10) cfile
```

Comment: I know this. This can be done only if the name of the file is known beforehand. However,  in my case, I only know the extension after the dot '.'. I did not know the entire name of the file.

Comment: So do you know the name of the file at the time of the search? What exactly does the user enter?

Comment: In this case, I guess cfile will contain "test.nod", so it may useful to remove ".nod" in the Fortran side by using `n = index( cfile, ".nod" ) ; cfile = cfile( 1 : n-1 )`

Comment: @roygvib I agree, but bear in mind that it still has to be retained as .nod is not the only type of file that he is looking for (.elem for example) and the full file name is required for opening,reading and one assumes deleting once finished with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can do this by using the `system` command together with the `basename` command. Here, the obtained basename is saved in "_tmp_" and then read into a character string.

```
    character(50) :: base
    logical :: ok

    call system( "cd input; rm -f _tmp_; [ -f *.nod ] && basename *.nod .nod > _tmp_" )

    inquire( file="input/_tmp_", exist=ok )
    if ( ok ) then
        open( 10, file="input/_tmp_", status="old" )
        read( 10, * ) base
        close( 10 )
        print *, "basename = ", trim(base)
    else
        stop "*.nod not found :("
    endif

    ! open( 20, file=trim(base) // ".rst" )    ! open new files
```

If there are many *.nod files and all the base names need to be extracted, it may be useful to do something like this (thanks to @Vladimir and @RolfofSaxony):

```
!> A pattern using for loops in the shell script.
! call system( "cd input; rm -f _tmp_; for f in *.nod; do basename -s .nod $f >> _tmp_; done" )

!> Another pattern using -s option for basename command.
! call system( "cd input; rm -f _tmp_; basename -s .nod *.nod > _tmp_" )
```

If your compiler is sufficiently new, you can use `execute_command_line` in Fortran2008 ([Ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html#EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE)) which is the standardized version of `system` and makes the code more portable:

```
call execute_command_line( "...." )
```

Comment: Hmm but if there are more than one *.nod files in the input directory, this doesn't work... :(

Comment: It should be possible to add a for loop to the shell script to get multiple basenames to different lines in the file.

Comment: @VladimirF Yeah, but come to think of it, if there are multiple such files (like foo.nod and baa.nod), the basenames are no longer unique... I hope OP will get the idea about how to do it (incl. the other answer) :)

Comment: wouldn't `basename -s .nod *.nod` fix that?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thanks, updated. (I didn't know this -s option, seems useful for multiple files.)

Comment: Consider using execute_command https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html#EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE instead of system, if your compiler supports it, it is the standardized method for this task.

Comment: @haraldkl Thanks, updated! But frankly, I feel this command name is a bit too lengthy... (though the meaning is very clear).